# hover text issue in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a `plotly` plot, but I am having trouble with the hover text. In the plot made by the code below, it is very difficult to see hover text unless I move my mouse very carefully or if I zoom in very close to the peak. How can I fix this to make the hover text appear just bypassing my mouse over the peak, even if the peak is very thin like in this example?

```
library(plotly)
out = data.frame(x = seq(10000, length.out = 1000), y = rep(c(rep(0, 99), 100), 10))
plot_ly(
   x = out$x,
   y = out$y,
   type = "bar"
)
```

[image]

Comment: Your x variable is a continuous scale. Bar plot will work better for categorical variable or for histogram

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer, it work's so much better with ```as.factor(out$x)```

Comment: If you want to post as an answer I'll mark it complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, x variable is a continuous scale. Bar plot will work better for categorical variable or for histogram. Try converting the x variable as category variable and plot.